# e.offsetX, e.offsetY reports incorrect number

Tags: javascript, css

For some reason when I add the pointer e.offsetX and e.offsetY become inaccurate. This causes the pointer to jump around. Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

```js
theDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)

function mousemove(e) {
  pointer.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px'
  pointer.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px'
  console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
```

```css
#theDiv {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#pointer {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">
  <div id="pointer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`offsetX/Y` is calculated relative to the target you're hovering. When the `#pointer` comes under your mouse, the coordinates are relative to it (hence, small values), so it goes back to the top left, then the offset is high again, so it comes back, and so on.

But you can disable `pointer-events` on this pointer:

```js
theDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)

function mousemove(e) {
  pointer.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px'
  pointer.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px'
  console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
```

```css
#theDiv {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#pointer {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none; /* <------------------ */
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">
  <div id="pointer"></div>
</div>
```

Another way to do it is to use `pageX/Y` and calculate the offset of `#theDiv` yourself:

```js
theDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)

function mousemove(e) {
  // `this` will always be `#theDiv`
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      offsetX = e.pageX - rect.left,
      offsetY = e.pageY - rect.top;
      
  pointer.style.top = offsetY + 'px';
  pointer.style.left = offsetX + 'px';
  console.log(offsetX, offsetY);
}
```

```css
#theDiv {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#pointer {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">
  <div id="pointer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there some property other than ```offsetX``` that doesn't have this behavior?

Comment: There is `pageX/Y` (relative to the top left corner of the page; scroll included) and `clientX/Y` (relative to the viewport)

Comment: But nothing that is relative to the element that the event listener is added to?

Comment: Not natively, but it can easily be calculated. I added an example to the answer